# How to I access the value in the [[PromiseResult]] from axios?

Tags: promise, axios

I used Axios and get data from 'data.json' file.

```
const RoomItems = axios.get("./data.json")
.then((res) => { return res.data })
.catch(() => { console.log('fail') })
```

And after console.log like  `console.log(RoomItems)` ,
the result show like below

```
Promise
  __proto__: Promise
  [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
  [[PromiseResult]]: Array(3)
```

How can I access the value(=Array(3)) in the [[PromiseResult]] ?
I tried various methods to get this values, Array. But I couldn't.

I'd like to use `map()` but I can't because I can not access this array at [[PromiseResult]].

Comment: you can directly import the JSON file and use it. no need for the axios.

Comment: const RoomItem = require('./data.json');

console.log(RoomItem);

Answer (score 1):

RoomItems is Promise that's why it's showing, if You want a result use async/await.

```
async function abc() {
  const RoomItems = await axios
    .get("./data.json")
    .then((res) => {
      return res.data;
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log("fail");
    });

    console.log(RoomItems);
}
```

**OR**

```
const RoomItem = require('./data.json'); 
console.log(RoomItem);
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining in detail ! I’ll give it a try using async/await. thank you